# Use different Anaconda environments on Linux Mint and Spyder

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, linux-mint

I'm trying to use and install packages in more than one environment through **Anaconda 4.9.2** (I use **Linux Mint 20** and **Spyder 4.1.5**).
I created an environment called `phdenv`, and it seems to me that I was able to install **Python 3.7**, but when trying to activate the environment through the command `conda activate phdenv` the error that appears is the following:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

     $ init init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
   - bash
   - fish
   - tcsh
   - xonsh
   - zsh
   - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.



Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install Anaconda (not conda)? What shell are you using? What happens when you run `conda init`?

Comment: no change 
No action taken.